# ReInit в tinyMCE 4.7 (element re-creation)

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce

I need to delete part of the DOM with the elements of the editor. After that a new DOM tree will be created in which I need to initialize the editor.

```
tinymce.remove();
window.tinymce.editors = [];
tinymce.EditorManager.editors = [];

tinymce.EditorManager.init({ ... some code ...});
console.log(tinymce.EditorManager.editors);
```

Even though I try to delete the editor after initialization, these methods do not work.

Please suggest.

Comment: @OcasoProtal FYI `[ru.so]` gets automagically expanded to [ru.so].

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for that info. I always copy the link from the footer :)

Comment: Without seeing running code nobody will be able to help you.  Perhaps you can make a simple CodePen or JS Fiddle that shows exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle[dot]net/238fL1wd/

It's work!

My system deletes css dynamically, so it seems that TinyMCE has not been reinitialized.
Can someone knows how to add your attribute to the created Link tag of TinyMCE?